# CSS Rotate Portrait Image 90 Degrees and Make Image Full Screen

Tags: html, css, rotation, fullscreen, css-transforms

I have tried many variations.  Using an html img, using background image for an element.  The idea is that I rotate a portrait oriented image 90 to display on a sideways mounted display, (picture a 16:9 monitor laid on its side).  I would like the image to be full screen.  Here is my latest attempt.  I am using viewport scaling, but I have tried percentages and 'cover' and many combinations.  I know this is not right, nothing has right been so far.  The reason I have the vh and vw settings switched is because the running theory is that it still applies scaling and transformations on an image it thinks is portrait, even though it's been rotated to landscape.  It is confusing and a bit frustrating.  Thanks.

```css
.rotate {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.liftedsites.net/images/IMG_7863.jpg");
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate bg"> </div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to adjust the `transform-origin` and add some translation to rectify the position. You have to also add `overflow:hidden` to hide the overflow created by the element because transform is only a visual effect and will not modify the layout of the page and before the tranform you will for sure have an overflow since you inverted the viewport units:

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.bg {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate bg"> </div>
```

Comment: Produces a blank white page for me, using your image or mine.  I am grateful for the edits and the help though.

Comment: @Slid3r did you copy the exact code? you may notice am using `background` and not `backgound-image`

Comment: It is.  But ... I have no idea.  I will paste whole code.

Comment: `<html>
        <head>
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
                <title>Portrait Images</title>
                <!--  <img src = "IMG_7863.jpg"</img> -->
<style>
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(IMG_7863.jpg) center/cover;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="rotate bg"> </div>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Slid3r as I told you, you are using `background-image` and not `background`

Comment: I would like to say thank you.  For some reason, Chrome was not displaying this properly.  Then Firefox DID display it properly.  Opening a new tab in Chrome seemed to fix it there too.  `.bg {
  background: url(IMG_7863.jpg) center/cover;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
}'

This was correct.  I am grateful.

Comment: How can this be achieved for a video? any clues? @TemaniAfif