# How do I make the background image to fill the white spaces (on div) while rotating the image CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

```
#main-image-div {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/87/77/88/1000_F_87778829_SUQcfXnnxAvOJDMZBApGuDCh75lb7mIP.jpg);
    background-size: 200px;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}
```

I am changing the background size of the image through a text box and also changing its transformations to all type of rotations through buttons. This image covered all the white spaces when it was horizontally placed, but while rotating they create the white space. How do I fill those white spaces with the same image on the div(instead scaled zoom, i want to have same tiles of background-size to be filled on the white spaces. I tried all day, I could not resolve it. Please help on this thanks.

Comment: which white spaces? the div is square regardless of rotation

Comment: The background image is placed under div id called #main-image-div, and there is another div outside of this or parent div, I also added there overflow:hidden, so #main-image-div will not show outside the parent div ID. so parent div ID has those white spaces, because I rotated its child div. I want the parent divs to get filled with the same image with same background size or whichever I generate from textbox. Can it be possible?

Comment: sure, you could have the parent div with the same background image - but it won't be rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:141vmax;
  height:141vmax;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/87/77/88/1000_F_87778829_SUQcfXnnxAvOJDMZBApGuDCh75lb7mIP.jpg);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

Using a div:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  margin:50px;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:141vmax;
  height:141vmax;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://as1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/87/77/88/1000_F_87778829_SUQcfXnnxAvOJDMZBApGuDCh75lb7mIP.jpg);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if OP has content in the box, you'd need to add `z-index:-1;` to the `:before` CSS so that any content is visible - well done by the way, I thought this was going to be impossible :p always forget the power of `:before` and `:after`!

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I wonder when it comes to rotate 90deg, it is creating white spaces, can this be solved ?

Comment: @user3751835 90deg is a different story, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742059/8620333 ... there is no generic solution for all the angle, we need to deal with each one specifically

Comment: Hey Do you know if I can use background-size and background-repeat to show one image getting repeated only in img tag. Currently I was able to do that on my div, I wanna know the possibility of making that to img tag alone?

Answer (score -2):

you could set the #main-image-div's background-color to a certain color...which it's currently inheriting it looks like

Comment: https://www.patterndesigns.com/api, if you scroll down and see their demo, they have scale and rotation. I am trying to achieving a similar thing. so I tried with background-sizes through textbox and also scale, rotation with buttons. However, it creates a white spaces.