# Is it possible to change user's phone orientation using react?

Tags: reactjs, mobile

I have the next question. I am developing a react application with some images. The user has the possibility to click and open a full-page image. Because the image's orientation is horizontal on the mobile, it does not look good. My idea is when the user clicks on the full page icon, the orientation of the phone becomes horizontal as is implemented on youtube. I tried to find some information about that, but I am not sure if it is even possible, I saw that only by using react native and developing mobile applications you can have access to the user's orientation of the screen. But maybe there are some methods to do in the browser? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change this from the web, however you could simply rotate the image and display it full screen. This has been done here:

[CSS Rotate Portrait Image 90 Degrees and Make Image Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741753/css-rotate-portrait-image-90-degrees-and-make-image-full-screen)